# How To Turn A (Touch) Pencil Tool Into A Straight Line Tool?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, touch, lines

So far, it's mobile touch pencil tool, which can draw perfectly, but I'm wondering... how would I make it so that it draws a completely straight line instead of a basic pencil tool which can draw outside the line?

---

Here's the code so far:

```
// "Draw Line" Button
$(document).ready(function () {
         initialize();
      });


      // works out the X, Y position of the click inside the canvas from the X, Y position on the page
      function getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas) {
         var x, y;
         if (mouseEvent.pageX != undefined && mouseEvent.pageY != undefined) {
            x = mouseEvent.pageX;
            y = mouseEvent.pageY;
         } else {
            x = mouseEvent.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            y = mouseEvent.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
         }

         return { X: x - sigCanvas.offsetLeft, Y: y - sigCanvas.offsetTop };
      }

      function initialize() {
         // get references to the canvas element as well as the 2D drawing context
         var sigCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasSignature");
         var context = sigCanvas.getContext("2d");
         context.strokeStyle = 'Black';

         // This will be defined on a TOUCH device such as iPad or Android, etc.
         var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

         if (is_touch_device) {
            // create a drawer which tracks touch movements
            var drawer = {
               isDrawing: false,
               touchstart: function (coors) {
                  context.beginPath();
                  context.moveTo(coors.x, coors.y);
                  this.isDrawing = true;
               },
               touchmove: function (coors) {
                  if (this.isDrawing) {
                     context.lineTo(coors.x, coors.y);
                     context.stroke();
                  }
               },
               touchend: function (coors) {
                  if (this.isDrawing) {
                     this.touchmove(coors);
                     this.isDrawing = false;
                  }
               }
            };

            // create a function to pass touch events and coordinates to drawer
            function draw(event) {

               // get the touch coordinates.  Using the first touch in case of multi-touch
               var coors = {
                  x: event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
                  y: event.targetTouches[0].pageY
               };

               // Now we need to get the offset of the canvas location
               var obj = sigCanvas;

               if (obj.offsetParent) {
                  // Every time we find a new object, we add its offsetLeft and offsetTop to curleft and curtop.
                  do {
                     coors.x -= obj.offsetLeft;
                     coors.y -= obj.offsetTop;
                  }
                  // The while loop can be "while (obj = obj.offsetParent)" only, which does return null
                  // when null is passed back, but that creates a warning in some editors (i.e. VS2010).
                  while ((obj = obj.offsetParent) != null);
               }

               // pass the coordinates to the appropriate handler
               drawer[event.type](coors);
            }


            // attach the touchstart, touchmove, touchend event listeners.
            sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw, false);
            sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw, false);
            sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw, false);

            // prevent elastic scrolling
            sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();
            }, false); 
         }
         else {

            // start drawing when the mousedown event fires, and attach handlers to
            // draw a line to wherever the mouse moves to
            $("#canvasSignature").mousedown(function (mouseEvent) {
               var position = getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas);

               context.moveTo(position.X, position.Y);
               context.beginPath();

               // attach event handlers
               $(this).mousemove(function (mouseEvent) {
                  drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
               }).mouseup(function (mouseEvent) {
                  finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
               }).mouseout(function (mouseEvent) {
                  finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
               });
            });

         }
      }

      // draws a line to the x and y coordinates of the mouse event inside
      // the specified element using the specified context
      function drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context) {

         var position = getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas);

         context.lineTo(position.X, position.Y);
         context.stroke();
      }

      // draws a line from the last coordiantes in the path to the finishing
      // coordinates and unbind any event handlers which need to be preceded
      // by the mouse down event
      function finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context) {
         // draw the line to the finishing coordinates
         drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);

         context.closePath();

         // unbind any events which could draw
         $(sigCanvas).unbind("mousemove")
                     .unbind("mouseup")
                     .unbind("mouseout");
      }
```

Thanks,
Wardenclyffe

Answer (score 1):

Anchor the pen down point at first touch and then wherever the next touch is draw a straight line from the first touch to the new touch. Have a floating check mark above the new touch to accept the new line. If the check mark isn't selected and there is another touch then remove the previous line, draw a new line, and show another check mark to save the new line. Provide an (x) above the original pen down point to cancel the line drawing tool.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a straight line tool and a pencil tool is that the pencil draws as many points as possible, and connects them with (possibly smoothed) line segments. A straight line tool connects a small number of lines with relatively large line segments.

One option would be for the pencil tool to lay down points as long as the finger touches the screen. And then the line tool draws from tap to tap. Alternately, if you tap and slide, the line tool could rubber-band the line from the touch point to the drag point, and then keep the last point before the touch lifts.